# How to deal with the miss# how to deal with the missing values in time series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, forecasting, pandas

I have dataset in which there are records of stock market hour by hour. There are some missing values like each day should posses 24 values as it is hour
by hour but I don't have the value of some hours and there is one more case that the whole day is not present in dataframe . How to deal with this type
of usecase ?

Comment: It depends on the purpose and nature of your analysis.  Please tell us a little more about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: I want to apply the forecasting on the dataset hourly basis but I have the dataset in which some records are not present .

Comment: Please tell me that which feature should I use Open, High, Low, Close.  I want to use Close that indicating market is closing and what does it means if we have dataset hourly basis that market is closing hour by hour ?. Please little bit elaborate me. Is it possible